# How to compile a whole c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compilation

i am trying to execute a program. I have no experience with c++. I got this network generator code and wanted to try it. However, i am not able to compile it. I have tried to open a solution and then add files to visual studio, gave me errors for libraries, then tried to compile with the command prompt of visual studio, again gave me error. The readme file only says that:

-------------------- How to compile -----------------------------------

In order to compile, type:

make

I typed 'make' to every place i have found if this command is known, not working. How can i compile this project? The libraries throw several coding errors like "X variable is not declared"...etc. I don't think that the library is badly written. How to compile a project with its libraries? The direct download link and the file root link is given below. Thank you for helping me with this small problem.

A direct download link is here: https://sites.google.com/site/andrealancichinetti/files/binary_networks.tar.gz?attredirects=0&d=1

The project is here, the first one: 
https://sites.google.com/site/andrealancichinetti/files

Comment: I appreciate how hard this is, especially because I couldn't do it either, but SO isn't suited for questions like this. You're going to need to get familiar with a whole load of stuff in c++ and a single SO question isn't the first place. Sorry man

Comment: Yes, i know and i appreciate the desire of making all questions at a certain standard and quality, i really didn't want to ask this kind of question here but i am really lost. I have tried every method i know to compile but didn't work. I think that that is because of libraries. But i do want to know that if it is my problem or the errors are in the code so ih ave nothing to do about it. The last 3 hours i spent on this, and couldn't manage anything. If noone answers, i will not judge.

Comment: `make` is a program that reads a file with "recipes" in it, and executes proper commands to assemble those recipes. There are various forms of `make` out there, from various parties and compiler makers. A popular one is [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Steve. I think GNU make can be a solution here. If you want to make this as an answer, i will accept it as an correct answer and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Without posting any code, answers to these will be difficult but, to get you started I will post some beginner related stuff here.

I would recommend to first watch a video on how to use visual studio C++:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PAn2V3j1wA

This video will show how to compile a project.

And then, I would recommend getting some basic understanding in C++ or you will be overwhelmed with everything. Here is a good site to get started:

http://www.learncpp.com/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for contribution. I have watched these kind of stuff before writing this shitty question here, but most of them are compiling "hello world" files. My problem is based on compiling the libraries. Libraries that is written by the developers of the code. They have some errors, and i do want to know them whether they are my problem to not able ot compile or this code has this error (means uncompilable code).

Comment: If you have a good foundation in C++, then debugging through the library will not be as hard. In my own experience, when I get an issue with a library compiling, it is usually because I did something wrong rather then the library itself. I would recommend posting a question to a forum that the library has (if there is one). Or, edit this question and Delibes the exact error that you are receiving. The more detailed question, the more detailed answer

Comment: i have specified the quiestion with the libraries. I hope someone helps. Also as you can see in the second link, this is a google sites, like a personal web site. No forum, only email can be sent and i already sent.